# How to Apply If Statement for both Capital & Small Letters

Tags: php, string-comparison

I want to add one If Statement in my script. If it gets any of the name mentioned, it converts it to admin. If script gets name like arsh, then it convert it to admin. But if script gets name like ARSH, Arsh, arSh, arsH then It should also convert it to admin... I can't manually define each work manually. So looking for a good way to get this work done.

```
if ($name=='arsh' || $name=='saif' || $name=='john' || $name=='smith'){
    $name = 'Admin';
}
```

convert capital or small letters name to admin

Comment: An idea, before entering in the if statement you can do lowercase($name) and then check it.

Answer (score 2):

You may compare the lowercase input name against lowercase literals:

```
$lname = strtolower($name);
if ($lname == 'arsh' || $lname == 'saif' || $lname == 'john' || $lname == 'smith') {
    $name = 'Admin';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) which doesn't require changing the case or mutating your variable:

```
if (strcasecmp($name, 'arsh') === 0 || strcasecmp($name, 'saif') === 0 || strcasecmp($name, 'john') === 0 || strcasecmp($name, 'smith') === 0){
    $name = 'Admin';
}
```

Or just convert the names to either [upper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) or [lowercase](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) before you do your comparison. Just make sure you assign it to another variable if you need to have the original value unaltered.

```
$name = strtolower($name);
if ($name=='arsh' || $name=='saif' || $name=='john' || $name=='smith'){
    $name = 'Admin';
}
```